# Proxmox on Hetzner, single IP, routed configuration

Tags: iptables, nat, proxmox, hetzner

Alright, I'm at my wits end.

I am trying to configure a ProxMox on dedicated server at Hetzner, which has one public IP, so I want to use NAT for VMs / containers.

I read all the manuals, and tried to follow [Hetzner's](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-proxmox_ve) manual to the letter. It simply doesn't work.

Here's my config:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.16/27
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
        pointopoint xxx.xxx.xxx.1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  xxx.xxx.xxx.16
    netmask  255.255.255.255
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

iface eth0 inet manual
```

The guest is simply:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.2/24
        gateway 10.0.0.1
```

When I create an LXC with interface attached to `vmbr1`, it doesn't have internet connectivity.
When I do `ping -I vmbr1 google.com` I get timeouts (and so it's for `vmbr0` which is strange)

I think this is the most minimalistic configuration and is recommended everywhere. `ip route` shows that `vmbr0` is `linkdown` - which AIUI means it's attached to an interface which is down - but it's not attached to anything really, and this is by design?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I do not think that you followed it to the letter, no offense. Host Bridged configuration says `bridge_ports enp1s0` for vmbr0. Yours does not. Host System Routed configuration says `up ip route add <first additional IP>/32 dev vmbr0`. Yours does not. Which configuration example did you follow? In your configuration your bridge interface is not connected to any network interfaces, rendering it guest-only I think.

Comment: What `vmbr0` is for? Why you ever defined that interface? (Please, don't answer that "it was in the manual", because the follow-up would be "did you understand why it was in that manual".) // I don't see any place in your post where you actually create a NAT rule in the host. I don't see a place which describe how you instruct a host kernel to forward IP packets. Both are needed to route and NAT packets for VMs on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I got to the answer:

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

No bridging is needed.

As Nikita pointed out above, `vmbr0` in the example above was not needed, so I killed it and moved `vmbr1` up the stack.

What surprises me most, is that Hetzner's manual doesn't mention the port forwarding part at all - which surprised me a great deal, even though I'm not really a networking guru by any stretch of imagination. So, here you go, hope it'll be helpful to someone.

Comment: `-s 'public.ip.0/24'` seems very strange to me. I'd rather filter by the local network here, e.g. `-s 10.0.0.0/24`, so only local network (consisted of virtual machines) would be able to use this NAT rule.

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly dubbed that one out. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

On your vmbr0 block "post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE"

Is -o ens3 correct? will it be enp4s0?

Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/528184)